# Possible to detect hardware?

Tags: hardware

Is it possible to detect the hardware of a machine using a Framework such as Asp .NET or Ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no; a web server is limited by the information sent by the client in the [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Comment: Thanks, have any idea if its possible with adobe air or flash?

Comment: @atbyrd Possibly.  Adobe Air can read certain information such as [network interface information](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/retrieving_network_interfaces.html).   What info are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I would want to know pretty much all the major components, Motherboard, Processor, Video Card , etc...

Comment: @atbyrd I would look into what Adobe Air and possibly Microsoft Silverlight can offer you.  Since these technologies communicate through the browser between server-side and client-side components, you can pass more information than just what the HTTP headers will offer you.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I just thought of. Client-Side  C# code would probably be very useful.